# How do I check if the same user replies to my discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically I am trying to make a pollbot (which is inspired by PollMaster bot) and started making a Poll creation wizard but currently anyone can reply to my bot:

```
#Basic Poll Creation Wizard Command
@client.command(name = 'create')
async def create(context):

    #Author Check Function
    def check(author):
        def inner_check():
            if message.author != author:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        return inner_check

    #Sets The Question For The Poll
    setquestion = discord.Embed(title = '**Poll Maker**', color = 0x0f00ff)
    author = context.message.author
    setquestion.set_footer(text = f'{str(author)[:-5]}\'s poll', icon_url = context.message.author.avatar_url)
    setquestion.add_field(name = f'What are you asking?', value = 'What is the question you have, try to be as descriptivve \nas possible without typing an annoying long question.')
    await context.message.channel.send(author.mention, embed = setquestion)
    question = (await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)).content

    #Determines Whether Or Not The Author Wants The Poll To be Anonymous
    isanonymous = discord.Embed(title = '**Poll Maker**', description = f'Nice, you\'ve got your question; now decide \nwhether or not you want the poll to be anonymous.\n \n`0 - No`\n`1 - Yes`\n \nAn anonymous poll has the following effects: \n:small_blue_diamond: You will never see who voted for which option', color = 0x0f00ff)
    isanonymous.set_footer(text = f'{str(author)[:-5]}\'s poll', icon_url = context.message.author.avatar_url)
    await context.message.channel.send(author.mention, embed = isanonymous)
    anonymous = (await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)).content
    while True:
        try:
            anonymous = int(anonymous)
            break
        except:
            await context.message.channel.send(f'{author.mention} **Please enter a valid number (either 0 or 1)**', delete_after = 3)
            anonymous = (await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)).content
```

This is what I have so far and I want to make sure that only the author of the original message can reply to my bot. Thank You for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check function is wrong

```py
def check(author):
    def inner(message):
        return message.author == author
    return inner

# To use it
m = await client.wait_for('message', check=check(context.author))
```

If you'd like to use it without the inner function

```py
def check(message):
    return message.author == context.author

m = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```